# How to change time-zone settings from the command line

Tags: command-line, time, timezone

I have a virtual machine that is set to **PST** that a couple of colleagues have in different time-zones.

If I wanted to change the time-zone to **EST** and **GMT**, what do I need to do?

Comment: Or easily `echo UTC > /etc/timezone`

Answer (score 375, accepted):

Use [`timedatectl`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/timedatectl.1.html)

```
sudo timedatectl set-timezone <timeszone>
```

---

Examples:

- Timezone as EST

  ```
    sudo timedatectl set-timezone EST
  ```
- Timezone as UTC

  ```
    sudo timedatectl set-timezone UTC
  ```
- Listing all valid Timezones

  ```
    timedatectl list-timezones
  ```

---

This command is **perfect** for automation scripts since it doesn't require any **user interaction** while compared to the other given answer based on `dpkg-reconfigure tzdata`.

Comment: Not a fan of +1 comments, but am putting one here since this worked for me in the best way. I was wanting a single one-line command line tool to change the timezone, rather than wanting to launch some whole either menu or gui program (I don't know what `tzdata` does, how it works, but I don't need to with this one line command). Thanks!

Comment: works like a charm ;)

Comment: Interestingly, it is doing something a little different than tzdata.  I had an issue with Java time being different than the system time after applying a patch.  Tzdata didn't work to fix the issue, but this did.

Comment: this didn't work for me; however the `dpkg-reconfigure` did the trick.

Comment: 14.04.4 ubuntu server

Comment: Not only did the timedatectl report anything or give wrong status, the timezone was still wrong in `date` commands run from the shell; the `dpkg-reconfigure tzdata` and switching to UTC was instantaneous - even the time on zsh prompt jumped to another timezone

Comment: @AnttiHaapala, thanks for sharing :) i'll check that. Any change you had [NTP / VM Hypervisor tools] race conditioned your command ?

Comment: I don't think so.

Comment: A quick note that this command is meant for `systemd`-based installations. If your system is an older version, then you may need to rely on `tzdata` instead.

Comment: Note, this `timedatectl` solution persists after a reboot. No need for any additional steps to make it reboot safe!

Comment: Perfect, I use timedatectl set-timezone America/Maceio it's works.

Comment: You might want to mention `tzselect` to find the desired timezone string.

Comment: Works on OL 7.9, Ubuntu and Redhat.

Answer (score 61):

As root you have to execute:

```
dpkg-reconfigure tzdata
```

A menu based tool should be started that allows you to change the timezone.

Comment: This also works on an install where `timedatectl` is not available (such as in some Docker containers).

Answer (score 41):

The following also work.  For GMT:

```
ln -sf /usr/share/zoneinfo/GMT /etc/localtime
```

For EST:

```
ln -sf /usr/share/zoneinfo/EST /etc/localtime
```

Comment: I think it would be better to link one of the city files rather than GMT or EST, as then they will keep track of daylight savings time, whereas linking (e.g.) GMT will not change the system time to reflect when daylight savings is in effect in your city. e.g.: `ln -sf /usr/share/zoneinfo/Europe/London /etc/localtime`

Comment: this is the best

Comment: I would caution against this.  If something or someone accidentally overwrites /etc/localtime you have just lost your zoneinfo file.  It's better to just copy the zoneinfo file over the /etc/localtime file.

Comment: On docker images `timedatectl` may not be installed out of the box, and it is really overkill to install a tools just to change time zone. This is the only answer that allow setting timezone with system command only. In this sense, I would say this is the best answer.

Answer (score 28):

The most ease way especially to a server is to list timezones:

```
timedatectl list-timezones
```

And choose yours, for example:

```
timedatectl set-timezone Europe/Athens
```

Thats it! , :-)

Answer (score 7):

Edit the `timezone` file at the `/etc` folder as:

```
Etc/GMT
```

You can use the next format:

```
Region "/" City
```

Example of `/etc/timezone`:

```
Europe/Athens
```

or

```
Europe/Paris
Europe/London
```

You may experiment with the: `dpkg-reconfigure tzdata`
and check cat the timezone file.

You must reboot or start again a service (not the ntp service). I do not know which one.
If somebody knows please share with us. 
(Tested on Ubuntu 15.10 the change is taken into account instantly)

Answer (score 6):

To run one program with a different time zone setting, set the `TZ` environment variable, e.g. run `TZ=Pacific/Kiritimati date` to see what time it is on Christmas Island, or `export TZ=Pacific/Kiritimati` to have the setting last for a shell session.

Answer (score 6):

```
cp -p /usr/share/zoneinfo/US/Pacific /etc/localtime
```

I recommend AGAINST linking like mentioned by others.  If some script accidentally over writes your `/etc/localtime` file, then it overwrites your Pacific timezone file... and it's a bit of a pain to replace it.

Just copy the Pacific file over the localtime file with the command above.

Comment: This actually worked for me. I think there's some bug with Docker, ansible (?). Both timedatectl and dpkg-reconfigure tzdata failed for me. After I copied, the time zone changed from EST to PDT.

Answer (score 2):

I use the following script to ask the user which timezone to set, and then confirm it has indeed been set:

```
#!/bin/sh
sudo timedatectl set-timezone $(tzselect)
echo
echo timedatectl says:
timedatectl
```

I call it `tz-set`.

Answer (score 0):

As root you have to execute:

`ln -fs /usr/share/zoneinfo/Europe/Warsaw /etc/localtime && dpkg-reconfigure --frontend noninteractive tzdata`

Comment: Please explain at least how this command works to change the timezone.

Comment: I get 
> tzdata is not installed

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me on GCP Ubuntu 14 via SSH

1. `sudo su`
2. `cp /usr/share/zoneinfo/Asia/Singapore /etc/localtime`
3. Restart the server
4. Done