# How to change timezone?

Tags: timezone

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to change time-zone settings from the command line](https://askubuntu.com/questions/3375/how-to-change-time-zone-settings-from-the-command-line)

I've installed Ubuntu in my laptop while I was travelling in other country. When I was back, I tried to change my time zone back, but every time I restart the computer, the time zone goes back to the one of the country where I installed Ubuntu.