# Change timezone in 10.04/11.04 without user input

Tags: configuration, setup, date, headless

How can one change the time-zone in Ubuntu 10.04 or 11.04 server from the command line without user input (e.g. `tzconfig EST`).

While one would use `dpkg-reconfigure tzdata`, per the related question [How to change the time-zone settings from the command line](https://askubuntu.com/questions/3375/how-to-change-time-zone-settings-from-the-command-line), with user interaction, I can't seem to find out how to change the time-zone from within a non-interactive a script.

The solution is meant to be part of an installation script that configures a server.

Thank you for reading.

Answer (score 13):

Create a link to /etc/localtime

```
ln -sf /usr/share/zoneinfo/America/Los_Angeles /etc/localtime
```

Just replace /America/Los_Angeles with your zone.

Comment: /etc/localtime is a copy of the timezone file, found in /usr/share/zoneinfo/

Comment: This looks like a really weird way of setting the time, but [that's what `tzconfig` does internally](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/dapper/man8/tzconfig.8.html), so I guess it's correct.

Answer (score -2):

Goto Systems > Administration > Time and Date.

Then press the padlock icon beside "Click to make changes", enter your password to authenticate, now you can change your Time Zone.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Nice pictures, but I think you have misread the question. Thank you for your post, albeit not answering the question. :)