# What is the command line statement for changing the System clock?

Tags: command-line

Is there such command for changing the System clock's date and time?

For example:

The current date and time is `January 1, 1970 22:30:59:980` where *59* and *980* refers to the *seconds* and *millisecods* respectively

And I want to change it to `January 2, 1971 23:31:59:990`

Is there a command for this?

Comment: Just in case someone is interested in also changing the time zone.
http://askubuntu.com/questions/3375/how-to-change-time-zone-settings-from-the-command-line

Answer (score 66, accepted):

To set the time in Ubuntu from the terminal, you can use the following command:

```
sudo date new_date_time_string
```

where `new_date_time_string` has to follow the format `MMDDhhmmyyyy.ss` which is described below:

- `MM` is a two digit month, between 01 to 12
- `DD` is a two digit day, between 01 and 31, with the regular rules for days according to month and year applying
- `hh` is two digit hour, using the 24-hour period so it is between 00 and 23
- `mm` is two digit minute, between 00 and 59
- `yyyy` is the year; it can be two digit or four digit
- `ss` is two digit seconds. Notice the period `.` before the `ss`.

Source: [Manage Time in Ubuntu Through Command Line](http://codeghar.wordpress.com/2007/12/06/manage-time-in-ubuntu-through-command-line/).

So, in your particular case, you can use:

```
sudo date 010224311971.59
```

Or, you can use:

```
sudo date --set="1971-01-02 23:31:59.990"  && date --rfc-3339=ns
```

which is exactly what you asked.

Source:

- [How do I set current Unix time in milliseconds?](https://serverfault.com/a/338395/181186)

Comment: what is the actual format of the string date?

Comment: does that mean the accuracy can only be limited to *seconds*?

Comment: @AbelMelquiadesCallejo See my new edits.

Comment: Could someone explain? `hh` is between 00 and 23, but OP and this answer show it being set to 24.

Comment: @CarlH Great catch on that! See the new edits

Answer (score 21):

The easy way:

```
ntpdate -s ntp.ubuntu.com
```

To change the timezone:

```
dpkg-reconfigure tzdata
```

Probably you need `sudo`.

Comment: Which NTP server is going to set the time to January 1971, I wonder.

Comment: Is your server connected to internet? Check official documentation at https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/NTP.html

Answer (score 6):

You can use the `date` command to change the time and you'll need `sudo` permission to do it; an example to set the date to 27 June 2014 and the time to 1:17 AM is:

```
sudo date --set "27 Jun 2014 1:17:00"
```

Answer (score 6):

Since systemd was introducted in Ubuntu, the correct way is:

```
# timedatectl set-time "RFC 3339-compliant string"
```

e.g.

```
# timedatectl set-time "2002-10-02T10:00:00-05:00"
# timedatectl set-time "10:35"
# timedatectl set-time "+2 hours"
```

Comment: This also works with e.g. `sudo date --set="+2 hours"`, which is exactly what I needed.

Comment: Setting time zones: `timedatectl set-timezone America/New_York`

Answer (score 1):

Short versions for setting date or time only:

To set the date (will set the time to 0:0:0):

```
date +%Y%m%d -s "19710102"
```

To set the time only:

```
date +%T -s "23:31:59"
```

You could add the desired ".990" to the seconds.

[Read the man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/date.1) for more options and formats regarding the date command:

```
man date
```

Note: you may also want to check or set the hardware clock. [Read about it here](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/hwclock.8).

Answer (score -3):

```
sudo date --set="Mon Feb 16 08:49:56 IST 2015"
```

That would be correct statement in UBUNTU 14.04.

Comment: For everyone in the IST timezone only? Does the other answer not work for you?

Comment: The question doesn't require changing the timezone.