# Ubuntu-Core Snappy ssl-certificate error

Tags: ssl, ubuntu-core

yesterday i was testing the new ubuntu core image for the raspberry pi 2. Everything started perfectly but i got an ssl-certificate error for every snappy command i wanted to execute. 
Internet connection works and everything else is alright except snappy cant connect to server.
I will post the exact failure when im back at home.
(Everything was alright as i tested ubuntu core in a vm)

thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will need to check the time on the system. Most probably your Rasp is issuing the wrong time to the OS and the Certs become void. Issue the    `date`    command and check the time. If it is wrong issue

```
 sudo date new_date_time_string
```

where new_date_time_string has to follow the format MMDDhhmmyyyy.ss which is described below:

```
MM is a two digit month, between 01 to 12
DD is a two digit day, between 01 and 31, with the regular rules for days according to month and year applying
hh is two digit hour, using the 24-hour period so it is between 00 and 23
mm is two digit minute, between 00 and 59
yyyy is the year; it can be two digit or four digit
ss is two digit seconds. Notice the period . before the ss
```

With the proper time in place. It should most probably solve the issue.

Source: [What is the command line statement for changing the System clock?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/342854/what-is-the-command-line-statement-for-changing-the-system-clock) && I ran into the same problem with my Beaglebone