# Couldn't create temporary file to work with /var/lib/apt/lists/...bionic_InRelease

Tags: 18.04, package-management, lts

I don't remember installing anything recently but when I pulled my laptop out of standby today I got the following notification:

[image]

In words:
`An error occurred, please run Package Manager from the right-click menu or apt-get in a terminal to see what is wrong.
The error message was: Error: Opening the cache (E:Couldn't create temporary file to work with /var/lib/apt/lists/de.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu__dists__bionic__InRelease - mkstemp (2: No such file or directory),
E:The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.)'. This usually means that your installed packages have unmet dependencies`

(Side question: Is there a log file somewhere to copy the text from?)

I don't know what the right-click menu is. When I click on preferences, `Software & Updates` opens up, but I'm unsure what to do there.

running `apt-get check` diplays

`Reading package lists... Error!
E: Couldn't create temporary file to work with /var/lib/apt/lists/de.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_bionic_InRelease - mkstemp (2: No such file or directory)
E: The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.`

I have since tried:
per https://sillycodes.com/quick-tip-couldnt-create-temporary-file/:

`sudo apt-get clean
sudo mv /var/lib/apt/lists /tmp
sudo mkdir -p /var/lib/apt/lists/partial
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get update`
reverted with 
`sudo mv /tmp /var/lib/apt/lists`

There were error messages for several repositories, examplary:
`W: GPG error: http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease: Couldn't create temporary file /tmp/apt.conf.tiVq7R for passing config to apt-key
E: The repository 'http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.`

Comment: As suggested here https://askubuntu.com/questions/1059217/getting-release-is-not-valid-yet-while-updating-ubuntu-docker-container, restart fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This same error happened with my Ubuntu 18.04.
Then I reboot twice until it didn't start more.
Instead, the boot initramfs started.

Then, I run the 3 commands:

```
(initramfs) exit
...
(initramfs) fsck /dev/mapper/ubuntu–vg-root -y
...
(initramfs) reboot
...
```

PS.: I guess that had occurred any disk error after the last upgrade kernel. This already occurred in recent past two or three times.

Answer (score 0):

Rebooting the computer solved the problem this time, however the `Error: Opening the cache (E:Couldn't create a temporary file to work with /var/lib/apt/lists/)` indicates that there may be an underlying problem with bad blocks on your standby laptop's hard drive. In that case `sudo badblocks -s /dev/sdX` where **X** is replaced by Device's letter in the Disks application will probably also report that there are bad blocks. To fix bad blocks boot from the same Ubuntu live USB/DVD that you used to install Ubuntu and run `fsck` to check and optionally repair the filesystem by following the instructions in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1359041/).

Before performing a live check, you can do a test run with `fsck`. Pass the `-N` option to the `fsck` command to perform a test:  <sup>[source](https://phoenixnap.com/kb/fsck-command-linux)</sup>

```
sudo fsck -N /dev/sdX
```

The output prints what would happen, but does not perform any actions.