# Got problem while trying to login after rebooting the computer due to poor response to some tasks and bad internet connections

Tags: fsck

The image describes the actual problem encountered:

[image: The image describes the actual problem encountered]

Comment: The error is self explanatory, You need to run `fsck` manually. Does [How to run fsck on the root partition](https://askubuntu.com/a/1359041/767056) answer your question?

Comment: Yeah it works , thanks @stumblebee

Comment: Does this answer your question? [fsck error on boot: /dev/sda6: UNEXPECTED INCONSISTENCY; RUN fsck MANUALLY](https://askubuntu.com/questions/697190/fsck-error-on-boot-dev-sda6-unexpected-inconsistency-run-fsck-manually)