# How to manipulate date keeping the same time via command line

Tags: date

I am in a need of manipulating the system time for few minutes.

Say I need to keep the time as it is and change the date to next date.
After few minutes.. I need to go back to the normal time with out giving any manual inputs.

How is this possible with command line only.

I have gone through this [What is the command line statement for changing the System clock?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/342854/what-is-the-command-line-statement-for-changing-the-system-clock) and it requires to input date+time.

I dont want to change the time, only the date.
Once the requirement is done that is after few minutes, I dont want to enter any manual inputs for date and time..

I want to go back to regular time with command line.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the command line statement for changing the System clock?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/342854/what-is-the-command-line-statement-for-changing-the-system-clock)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an example of what ( I think ) you want. It will change the year only to last year for 4 minutes then back to current date again. Your machine needs to be connected to the Internet for this to work:

```
sudo bash -c "timedatectl set-ntp off && date -s 'last year' && sleep 4m && timedatectl set-ntp on"
```

Answer (score 2):

For the below to work, you should first go to Settings → *Date & Time* and disable *Automatic Date & Time*.

You can then use the following command as a (long) one-liner:

```bsh
sudo date --set="2010-05-02 $(date '+%T')" && sleep 10 && sudo date -s "$(wget -qSO- --max-redirect=0 google.com 2>&1 | grep Date: | cut -d' ' -f5-8)Z"
```

The above command:

- Gets the current system time:

  ```bsh
  date '+%T'
  ```

  and sets the date to the one you wish, keeping the current time:

  ```bsh
  sudo date --set="2010-05-02 $(date '+%T')"
  ```

  In this example the date, which you may change to what you need, is `2010-05-02`.
- Keeps the altered date for the specified time interval using the `sleep` command. Here I have used `sleep 10` to keep the altered time for 10 seconds. You can add an `m`, `h`, or `d` suffix to `sleep`'s argument (here `10`) to specify the time in minutes, hours, or days, respectively.
- Reverts the time to the current time (requires internet access):

  ```bsh
  sudo date -s "$(wget -qSO- --max-redirect=0 google.com 2>&1 | grep Date: | cut -d' ' -f5-8)Z"
  ```

  Credits to [Shrukul Habib](https://askubuntu.com/a/683136/618353).