# Kubuntu 14.04 clock showing only UTC despite correct timezone

Tags: 14.04, kubuntu, time

My panel clock is showing time in UTC. This is recent behavior, and I believe it is a recent regression, but I'm not 100% sure so I'm posing this as a question first.

Here's a screenshot of the clock in the panel, along with the clock settings.

[image: Panel clock in UTC, timezone is correct (PDT)]

Here's the output of 'sudo dpkg-reconfigure tzdata' after taking the settings I had already selected:

```
Current default time zone: 'America/Los_Angeles'
Local time is now:      Thu Aug 27 11:51:33 PDT 2015.
Universal Time is now:  Thu Aug 27 18:51:33 UTC 2015.
```

It looks to my like my timezone is set correctly, but my panel clock is not.

Also, to reiterate, this is a new issue; my panel clock had been showing the correct time until this week.

Anyone know how to fix this issue? Is it a known bug?

Edit: I think this screenshot better shows the issue. The clock knows both the correct PST time and the correct UTC time and it knows which one I am. It's just displaying the wrong one.

[image: hover time shown]

Comment: Is this a dual boot Windows-Kubuntu machine? If so, the problem is known. See https://askubuntu.com/questions/169376/clock-time-is-off-on-dual-boot

Comment: This is a virtualbox system, but I don't think that has anything to do with it.

1. I just tried the UTC=no fix, no change.

2. Virtualbox has correctly set "Hardware clock is UTC"

3. Note that the panel clock *knows* it is displaying UTC. The timezone is shown in the screenshot. The problem isn't what time the system thinks it is; the problem is what timezone is being displayed.

Comment: Check this link: http://askubuntu.com/questions/3375/how-to-change-time-zone-settings-from-the-command-line

Comment: Are you sure that clock at the machine in question runs correctly? Ī̲ don’t ask about time zones, Ī̲ ask about (absolute) time.

Comment: @IncnisMrsi I don't understand the question--those were the correct times when I took those screenshots. It's displaying the UTC time in the taskbar instead of PST.

Comment: @karlos I literally posted the output of dpkg-reconfigure tzdata in the description above.

Comment: @Cory: What the `date` command reports just now?

Comment: Analysis of http://askubuntu.com/revisions/666552/3 , including its source (that features a "2015-09-08 20:45:40Z" label), suggests that the machine knows UTC time correctly.

Comment: @IncnisMrsi yes, that's what's so weird. It has the correct UTC time; it knows I'm in PST; it insists on displaying UTC. Here's the output you asked for:
`% date
Fri Sep 11 15:12:32 PDT 2015`
(This is the correct current local time. This bug is only with the panel clock!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right click on the widget and select **Digital Clock Settings > Time Zones** and make a selection in *Clock defaults to*.

Comment: This appears to be the correct way to change the setting I changed manually in the config file. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In the end I got desperate and just grepped for UTC in my home directory. So I discovered `~/.kde/share/config/plasma-desktop-appletsrc`

This config file, for me, contained these two lines:

```
timezone=UTC
timeZones=UTC
```

Removing these lines and logging out and back in fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This hit me over the weekend - Friday afternoon, it showed the correct time; Monday morning, it showed UTC.

I fixed it by right clicking the time, selecting "Digital Clock Settings", then checking "Show time zone" and clicking "Apply".

The "Show time zone" check box was unchecked when I looked at the settings - I don't know if it was checked before or not.