# Kubuntu clock display often shows wrong Timezone

Tags: display, time, clock

This is sort of related to, but not quite the same as: [Kubuntu 14.04 clock showing only UTC despite correct timezone](https://askubuntu.com/questions/666552/kubuntu-14-04-clock-showing-only-utc-despite-correct-timezone)

I have a laptop that *only* runs Kubuntu, I have the system clock set to use UTC, and the local Time Zone set to US NYC, which is the correct wat to have the system set up as I understand it.  In the clock display settings window, I have the clock set to show 'local' time.  However for some reason my clock often will display UTC instead of local time.  If I go into the display settings window, I find that everything is still set right, and when I exit from the settings window the clock will show local time like it should...

This is doesn't seem to hurt anything but it is a *pity* to keep having to fix it...

One of the comments in the above mentioned article suggested grepping for "UTC" in the home directory, and finding it in ~/.kde/share/config/plasma-desktop-appletsrc.  I did this and found

```
[Containments][1][Applets][7][Configuration]
announceInterval=0
calendarType=-1
dateStyle=2
defaultTimezone=Local
displayEvents=false
displayHolidays=true
holidaysRegions=us_en-us
holidaysRegionsDaysOff=us_en-us
plainClockColor=0,0,0
plainClockDrawShadow=true
plainClockFont=Ubuntu,20,-1,5,50,0,0,0,0,0
showSeconds=false
showTimezone=true
**timeZones=UTC
timezone=Local**
useCustomColor=true
useCustomShadowColor=false
```

I haven't tried messing with this - should I?

Any suggestions to make my clock display *always* show local time?

Answer (score 0):

to edit the time open a terminal and type `dpkg-reconfigure tzdata` this will allow you to set the timezone and save it, making sure to always show local time

Comment: Thanks, I just gave that a try, but I'm not expecting it to solve my problem, as the timezone is set properly already.  My problem is that the clock sometimes displays the UTC time instead of LOCAL time....